# How to vectorize text data in Pandas.DataFrame and then one_hot encoode it "inside" the model

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, one-hot-encoding, language-model

I try to implement sequence model (trained to predict next word) built on one-hot encoded vector sequences. My custom one-hot encoder works well. But just as exercise I want to do all things with tensorflow (inspired by Deep Learning with Python, chapter 11, which I can reproduce, but not with my data. One difference: in book tensorflow.dataset is used, not DataFrame). Let we have input data 'df':

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[['I', 'have', 'an', 'idea','xyz'],
                         ['This', 'idea', 'is', 'awesome', 'asd']],
                   columns=['cell_0_0','cell_0_1','cell_1_0','cell_1_1','next_word'])
```

First of all:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras 
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, LSTM, TextVectorization
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import RMSprop
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

Let's prepare data for the model.

1. Get text corpus and vocabulary:

```
Corpus = df.to_numpy().flatten().tolist()
Vocab  = sorted(list(set(Corpus)))
Vocab.insert(0, '[UNK]')
Vocab.insert(0, '')
print(Vocab)
```

Output: ['', '[UNK]', 'I', 'This', 'an', 'asd', 'awesome', 'have', 'idea', 'is', 'xyz']

2. Split 'df' into X and Y. As I want to use tensorflow.TextVoctorizer, X should be a vector of text, i.e. the dimension of X should be 2 (or 1?):

```
X = [[' '.join(Row[:-1])] for Row in df.to_numpy()]
Y = [[Row[-1]] for Row in df.to_numpy()]
```

3. Then vectorize input data:

```
X_vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=len(Vocab), output_mode="int", output_sequence_length=df.shape[1]-1, vocabulary=Vocab, standardize=None)
Y_vectorizer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=len(Vocab), output_mode="int", output_sequence_length=1, vocabulary=Vocab, standardize=None)

X_vectorized = X_text_vectorization(X)
Y_vectorized = Y_text_vectorization(Y)
print(X_vectorized.shape, Y_vectorized.shape)
```

Output: (2, 4) (2, 1)

```
print(X_vectorized[0], Y_vectorized[0])
```

Output: tf.Tensor([2 7 4 8], shape=(4,), dtype=int64) tf.Tensor([10], shape=(1,), dtype=int64)

So data is correctly vectorized.

Then I build the model:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(None,), dtype="int64", name="input_layer")
embedded = tf.one_hot(inputs, depth=len(Vocab))
layer1 = LSTM(32)(embedded)
outputs = Dense(len(Vocab), activation='softmax')(layer1)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='RMSprop')
model.fit(x=X_vectorized.numpy()
         ,y=Y_vectorized
         ,batch_size=256
         ,epochs=55
         )
```

Please, correct the built model or/and parameters in fit method. As a current version generates ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 11) are incompatible.
Is such 'dataflow' is correct or is it a wrong approach? Should data be vectorized and the one_hot encoded right in a model?

Comment: change your loss function to `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, since your labels are sparse

Comment: @AloneTogether, I spend a whole day googling, reading books and articles. You solved my problem in 30 seconds. Thank You. Viva stackoverflow.com